# C-c c c to invoke org-capture

Tags: key-bindings

In my doom-emacs, "C- n n" will invoke `org-capture`,
I want to change it to "C-c c c"  as

```
(global-set-key "\C-c c c" 'org-capture)
```

However, it does not work as expected.

How could set `C-c c c` to substitute `C-c n n`

I find such key Binding:

```
Key Bindings
doom-leader-map n n
doom-leader-notes-map n
general-override-mode-map C-c n n
global-map C-c c
mode-specific-map c
```

it seems that `general-override-mode-map C-c n n` will override anything I set.

Comment: C-c n say nothing, C-c n n invoked `org-capture`. @RichieHH

Comment: What does C-h k C-c n say? C-h k is mapped on my emacs to 'describe-key. Normally org-capture is tied to a three key chord, in my case C-c c, and then you type the letter mapped to the TYPE of capture eg a journal note, a todo or something else.

Comment: I cant comment on doom emacs. but (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture) is my set up. Then you select the capture type.

Comment: I updated the question `general-override-mode-map C-c n n` override anything I set. @RichieHH

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a prefix command.
Generally said this can be used to combine key bindings that fit together.
You will probably have already experienced that in specific modes.

Projectile for example has `C-c p ...` where `...` can be a lot of possible commands related to projectile.

Another Example would be Yasnippet with `C-c & ...` where `...` could be `C-n`, `C-s` or `C-v` for new, insert or view.

I for example use that for the terminal program I use.

```
(define-prefix-command 'term-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x .") 'term-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x . t") 'term)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x . s") 'shell)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x . e") 'eshell)
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
(define-prefix-command 'example-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'example-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c c") 'org-capture)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c ...") 'something-else)
```

Where `...` can be any keystroke

Answer (score 0):

I found myself having a similar problem with binding `M-x` in doom emacs. It appears that something like `(map! "M-x" 'helm-M-x)` does not work, but when you try to see how this binding is setup, you realize that it is setup within the map `general-override-mode-map`. So the solution is to do instead:

```
(map! :map general-override-mode-map "M-x" 'helm-M-x)
```

so you may want to do something like:

```
(map! :map general-override-mode-map "C-c c c" 'org-capture)
```

Note that there may be a better solution.